# How do I store data that it is inputted forever?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to take an input from someone and save it in a dictionary even after I end the program so that I can run it again and retrieve the information. How do I do this?

Comment: You have to write the output (e.g. the key-values of a dictionary)  in e.g.`.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the information to a file or database when the program ends and reload it when it starts. [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is one way you can do that.